# Is this backup daily and into a specific user's home directory?

Tags: find, backup

From https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html, there are two backups in the following example, where the first backup is done by `find` and `cp`, and the second by `rsync`. My question is about the first backup.

> I use rsync to backup my wifes home directory across a modem link each
>   night. The cron job looks like this
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> cd ~susan
> {
> echo
> date
> dest=~/backup/`date +%A`
> mkdir $dest.new
> find . -xdev -type f \( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 \) -exec cp -aPv "{}"
> $dest.new \;
> cnt=`find $dest.new -type f | wc -l`
> if [ $cnt -gt 0 ]; then
>   rm -rf $dest
>   mv $dest.new $dest
> fi
> rm -rf $dest.new
> rsync -Cavze ssh . samba:backup
> } >> ~/backup/backup.log 2>&1
> ```
>
> note that most of this script isn't anything to do with rsync, it just
>   creates **a daily backup** of Susans work **in a ~susan/backup/ directory** so
>   she can retrieve any version from the last week.
>
> The last line does
>   the rsync of her directory across the modem link to the host samba.
>   Note that I am using the -C option which allows me to add entries to
>   .cvsignore for stuff that doesn't need to be backed up.

My questions are

1. Is "in a ~susan/backup/ directory" specified by 'dest=~/backup/`date +%A`'?  Does `~` in `dest` mean the home directory of the user who runs the script, who might not be Susan so `~` might not mean `~susan`?
2. Is "a daily backup" specified by  `\( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 \)`? Does  `\( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 \)` mean files modified within the past 48 hours, instead of the past 24 hours?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is "in a ~susan/backup/ directory" specified by 'dest=~/backup/date +%A'?

Yes, so you're right, the implementation doesn't quite match the spec.

> Does ~ in dest mean the home directory of the user who runs the script, who might not be Susan so ~ might not mean ~susan?

Yes. But the script needs to run as `susan` or `root` anyway to be sure to access all of Susan's files. It's presumably intended to be run by Susan (or `cron` acting for her).

> Is "a daily backup" specified by ( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 )?

I would consider "daily" to be determined by what ever is running the script, presumably `cron` (or nowadays, a systemd timer).

> Does ( -mtime 0 -or -mtime 1 ) mean files modified within the past 48 hours, instead of the past 24 hours?

Yes. `-mtime 0` means "whose modification timestamp compared to now, rounded down to the nearest 24h, is 0 × 24h", and likewise for `-mtime 1`, so this finds everything modified in the last 48h (well, strictly less than 48h). You need this to catch a full 24 hours' worth of changes, taking into account start time variations with daily jobs.